# How to translate "clearance"?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, modern-life

How could I translate the word "clearance" to Latin?
I mean it in the sense of a security clearance, a background check to gain authorization to access some information or a location.
The most fitting words I found are *permissio*, *concessio*, *venia*, and *licentia*, but I'm not sure which (if any) would be good for the kind of use I described.
Perhaps I should take one of these nouns and supplement it with an adjective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that *comprobatio cautionalis* is close in meaning to the English phrase. It might be roughly re-translated as 'approval [granted] after taking precautions'.